# Ajax pagination inside of jquery tabs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I am facing some problem with pagination inside of jquery tabs .I have used Ajax pagination for that it works good but unfortunately when I click on any page no (in pagination) second time .Then it breaks  the link .
Please look at the front view how it works:
http://kelts.wpengine.com/7664-top-o-the-morning-312/
open recent related posts->click on any page of pagination

please make sure that I am using wp-pagination();.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(".larger.page").live("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var href = jQuery(this).attr("href");
                show_posts(href.replace(/.*page\//, ""));
            });
    show_posts(1);
    }); 
    function show_posts(l) {
        jQuery.get("<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/fetch-blog-post.php", {
                    pageno : l
                }, function(data) {
                    jQuery("#show_posts").html(data).show();
                });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: here is my code Here is my code: 

<script type="text/javascript">    
    jQuery(document).ready(function (){    jQuery(".larger.page").live("click",function (e){    e.preventDefault();    var href = jQuery(this).attr("href");    show_posts(href.replace(/.*page\//,"")); });
  show_posts(1); 
 });
function show_posts(l){
jQuery.get("<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/fetch-blog-post.php", {pageno : l},function(data){
jQuery("#show_posts").html(data).show();
}); 
}
</script>

Comment: Edit your question, this is unreadable.

Comment: There is a syntax error, `});` after `show_posts(1);` is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your selector `jQuery(".larger.page").live(...)` to `jQuery(".larger.page, .page.smaller").live(...)`.

Onces you visit a link the class `larger` is replaced by `smaller` that is why the link is broken in the second click.

Comment: oops somewhere it still shows problem...On previous or on last button of pagination..Can you Please take a look?

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try

```
$('.wp-pagenavi').on('click',function(){
   // code
});
```

because `.live` is deprecated from now on.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the problem is that you get paginator itself as part of the AJAX response and don't bind events to a new DOM elements.